# My new Wordpress theme works perfectly except I don't know how to limit the blog posts shown in the blog page

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

My theme supports pages, posts and blog category pages but my assigned blog page doesn't limit anything, it shows all posts no matter what.
I've already set the blog page to show only 5 latest posts.

I just want it to show an excerpt of the blog posts with a 'Read more...' link in the bottom.

How do I only show excerpts of posts in the blog page?

Current template:

```
    <div id="contentMain">
    <div class="left-section">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="body-top"></div>
    <div class="entry-content body-content">
    <?php 
    if (is_page()) {
    echo '';    
    }
    if ((is_single()) || (is_home())) {
    echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'; the_title(); '</h2>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php 
    if (is_page()) {
    the_content();  
    }
    if ((is_single()) || (is_home())) {
    echo '<h6>'; the_content(); '</h6>';
    echo '<hr />';
    }
    ?>           
    <?php  ?>                 
    </div>
    <div class="body-bottom"></div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
     </div>
     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the_excerpt() where you want an excerpt to show up rather than the_content(). So something like

```
<?php if (is_home()) {
    the_excerpt();
} else {
    the_content();
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if ((is_single()) || (is_home())) {
  echo '<h6>'; the_content(); '</h6>';
  echo '<hr />';
}
```

to this

```
if ((is_single())) {
  echo '<h6>'; the_content(); '</h6>';
  echo '<hr />';
}
if ((is_home())) {
  echo '<h6>'; the_content(); '</h6>';
  echo '<hr />';
}
```

That should fix what you are experiencing

Comment: Didn't notice any change. I just want the 'blog' page which lists all blog entries to show excerpts of each of the latest 5 posts that are shown there. Currently it shows the whole post on all of them.

Comment: sorry I've been up all night.  In 8hrs when I wake up if it's not answered I'll get the right answer for you.